# Using Google App Scripts/Sheets for a website CMS / REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, google-apps-script, content-management-system, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to use either [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) or the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) to host a REST API, so that I can make client-side content requests on a static web page? If so, how would I go about this?

I'm building a simple website hosted on GitHub, and I want to experiment with using a spreadsheet as a content management system, e.g. fetching a running list of projects with corresponding text, images, etc.

Forgive me if I completely misunderstood the capabilities of either/both of these applications, or overlooked a previous ask!

Comment: I think you would write the code just like you were writing a webapp and then publish it as API executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Sheets API with multiple languages.

Here you have the different quickstarts that show you how to do it: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts

Also you can create a Web App with Apps Script and embed it in your website: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web